# What coredata errors should I prepare for?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, error-handling

I have an app getting close to release date, but it occurred to me that wherever I have core data save and/or fetch requests I'm not really handling the errors other than to check if they exist and @throw them, which I'm sure will seem almost like nails on a chalkboard to more experienced programmers, and surely there's some kind of disaster waiting to happen.

So to be specific, what kinds of errors can I expect from A) Fetches, and B) Saves, and also C) in general terms, how should I deal with these?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see the [Core Data Constants Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Miscellaneous/CoreData_Constants/Reference/reference.html) to get an idea about what kind of errors you can expect to see in general.

For fetches, the most common issue is that the fetch returns an empty array. Make sure that your view controllers, datasources and delegates can handle an empty fetch. If you dynamically construct complex predicates, make sure catch exceptions from an invalid predicate.

Most save errors results from validation errors. You should have a error recovery for every validation you supply. One common and somewhat hidden validation error is not providing a required relationship.

One thing that trips people up with Objective-c is that errors and exceptions are slightly different critters than they are in other languages. In Objective-C an error is something that the programmer should anticipate and plan for in the normal operation of the application e.g. a missing file. By contrast an exception is something ***exceptional*** that the programmer wouldn't expect the app to have to routinely handle e.g. a corrupted file.

Therefore, in Core Data a validation failure would be an common expected and unexceptional ***error*** whereas as corrupted persistent store would be a rare, unexpected and highly exceptional ***exception***.

See the [Exceptions Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Exceptions/Exceptions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000012-BAJGFBFB) and the [Error Handling Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ErrorHandlingCocoa/ErrorHandling/ErrorHandling.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001806) for details.

Comment: So if I have very simple fetches, not built programmatically, no validations, just quickly browsing the core data constants reference, all I can find that could apply are general CoreData and general SQLite errors, which sound pretty limited and hard to prepare for, I guess I'll just have to trap my save operation (there's really only one) and exit gracefully if anything comes up.

Comment: That's pretty much it. Major errors are rare with Core Data and when they do occur, it usually caused by something external that you can't fix anyway.